# Is this expected that civiHR removes lots of features (eg activities and cases)?

Tags: civihr

So I'm trying to use civiHR. I understand that some features are still beta and some new custom screen don't work so well and I'm prepared to live with that

What I don't understand is that civiHR disable existing features, eg:
- list of the cases "recruitement" isn't displayed n the case tab 
- activity tab removed

Is this on purpose or a bug? I don't see the point of removing features that would still have a sense because HR introduces different workflows too.

Is there a way to let the existing features of CiviCRM enabled, even when using civihr?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Note: My comments are focused mostly on CiviHR <=1.4; for 1.5+, I haven't followed as closely.)

CiviHR is broken down into several different extensions. Each extension defines a different piece of the data-model/UI (eg for tracking job contracts or tracking qualifications). If you pick and choose these individually, it should be possible to load them onto a CiviCRM site without disabling/removing features.

One extension, `org.civicrm.hrui`, is particularly opinionated and aggressive about reworking the UI. Its primary purpose is to reshape the overall user-experience for standalone CiviHR deployments -- emphasizing HR-specific elements, de-emphasizing fundraising-specific elements, tweaking phrases/word-choices. It fills a role similar to Drupal's *installation profiles*.

If you're an experienced Civi implementer/consultant looking to add some HR elements to an existing Civi site, then you've probably used most of the same tricks as `hrui` (eg toggling components and toggling display preferences), and you'll probably disagree with some of the opinions in `hrui`. So skip it; you're not the target audience for that extension. Browse the list of extensions and pick the ones which are relevant.

Comment: Part of the difficulty is that each extension has a rather minimal description of what it does, and if it depends (or not) of other extensions ;)

Comment: For examples, some extensions seem to expect extended demographics (I think, I had errors until I enabled it), but it contains ethnic fields, that are strictly controlled in France (to the point of not being able to use a HR software that has them)

Comment: A few high-level extensions -- ```hrui```, ```hrrreport```, ```hrsampledata```, ```hrstaffdir``` -- would have broad dependencies on other extensions. A few low-level extensions -- ```hrcaseutils```, ```reqangular``` -- may show up frequently as dependencies. Otherwise, there shouldn't be many dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

We were told that CiviHR should be a completely separate install to CiviCRM and that is being designed to work quite independently, so this is no surprise.

Comment: To clarify: it's a separate instance, but even for that instance, I'd like to be able to see, for instance, the list of activities with a contact. I'm aware that using "normal" civicase types and the HR ones are potentially a problem, but this isn't what I'm trying to do ;)